# Is Perl module `Math::Base::Convert` thread-safe?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, thread-safety, radix

1. Can it be run in parallel threads/processes using `threads` or `Parallel::ForkManager` or `fork`?
2. Have I got the `Math::Base::Convert` usage syntax correct?

*The code below runs, but it doesn't appear to be running in parallel - only PID `0` is displayed.*

**Example:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.24.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Math::Base::Convert qw(:all);

my @numbers;
# decimal number limits
my $lower_limit = 1;
my $upper_limit = 999999999999999999;

# generate array of random decimal numbers
for (1..1000) {
    push @numbers, (int(rand() * ($upper_limit-$lower_limit)) + $lower_limit);
}

# create Math::Base::Convert object
my $bc = new Math::Base::Convert('dec', 'b62'); # convert from decimal to base62

# create Parallel::ForkManager object
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(32); # 32 threads
DATA_LOOP:
foreach my $number (@numbers) {
    # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
    my $pid = $pm->start and next DATA_LOOP;
    
    my $converted = $bc->cnv($number);
    
    say "PID: $pid - Converted $number:base10 to $converted:base62";
    
    $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
$pm->wait_all_children;

exit;
```

Comment: *"push @numbers, {int(rand() * ($upper_limit-$lower_limit)) + $lower_limit};"* : You are pushing a hash reference when you probably meant to just push the scalar ?

Comment: Re "*1.*", At a quick glance, I see a Pure Perl module with no dependencies or other external resources. If that's true, then yes, it's thread safe and fork-safe. (Note that C code would be way faster at this.)

Comment: Note that doing one conversion per fork (or thread) is a good first step, but something you'll want to change. You want to do more work than that per "job" to mitigate the overhead.

Comment: The hash ref is my bad...forgot to remove the brackets. Will edit them out. The new code runs, but it doesn't appear to be parallel - all using PID `0`.

Comment: *"all using PID 0"* : `$pm->start` always returns 0 for the child process, to get the PID of the child inside the child you can do `my $pid = $$`

Comment: Re "*`$pm->start` always returns 0 for the child process*", and non-zero for the parent process, which is why to use `next` whenever it's not zero.